# Network game: how to handle turn game (like ruzzle management)

Tags: ios, multiplayer, gkmatchmaker

I am wondering how to handle matches like do ruzzle in ios:
I have read [Game Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html) and seems not what i am searching for.

in ruzzle one player can play the game and the other can play it too, while all two player haven't finished, i can't go to the second.
`GKTurnBasedMatch` can't be because only one player at a time can make his move.
`Real-Time Matches`? but if a player accept to play, then disconnects, the forst player can finish and wait the answer of the opponent, while seems not be so in real-time matches

should i have a separate server that stores the game, or i can use some other apple API?
thanks